# Is "an independent and identically distributed RV with a pmf of..." a contradiction?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, information-theory

I have a question in an assignment that begins by saying "generate $n$ i.i.d. pseudorandom outcomes for the random variable $X$ with a pmf of $[1/21, 2/21, 3/21, 4/21, 5/21, 6/21]$. Isn't this statement a contradiction as the outcomes of an i.i.d. all have the same probability? Or am I misunderstanding the definition of an I.i.d.?

Comment: Essentially, you have a die where each of the six sides has probability $1/21,\ldots,6/21$ respectively. Generating $n$ i.i.d. samples from this pmf is the same as rolling this die $n$ times.

Comment: What does the i.i.d mean in this question so? How would the outcomes be different if the question only asked "generate $n$ pseudorandom outcomes for the random variable $X$ with a pmf of $[1/21,2/21,3/21,4/21,5/21,6/21]$"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have misunderstood. I think you are confusing IID with the (discrete) uniform distribution. Here are some definitions from Wikipedia.

> 1. In probability theory and statistics, a sequence or other collection of random variables is [independent and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) (i.i.d. or iid or IID) if each random variable has the same probability distribution as the others and all are mutually independent.
> 2. In probability theory and statistics, the [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) is a symmetric probability distribution whereby a finite number of values are equally likely to be observed; every one of n values has equal probability 1/n.

So when you say " the outcomes of an i.i.d. all have **the same** probability", that is not true. If $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ are IID, then they are independent and follow the same distribution, call it $F$. The distribution $F$ is **not** necessarily a uniform distribution. If it is, then your statement would be true. However, in your given example, $F$ is **not** uniform. Although it is not uniform, the generated outcomes are still IID. Omitting the IID condition would suggest to me that they are dependent somehow. In a simple, brief exercise, the condition might be dropped and simply be *implied*, but that might be considered a little careless or unwarranted.

Comment: The key difference being they have _the same probability **distribution**_, not _the same probability_.